# NSString stringWithFormat: with C array?

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays

I'm writing a program that calculates the Jacobi algorithm. It's written in Objective-C since it runs on a Mac, but the majority is written in standard C. I'm using a two-dimensional C array and an `NSArray` containing 5 `NSTextField` labels.

The following code yields an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
     NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", matrix[i][i] ];
     [[resultLabels objectAtIndex:i] setStringValue:resultString]; // error line
}
```

Any help?

## EDIT

Here's where I `init` `resultLabels`:

```
resultLabels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:result11, result22, result33, result44, result55, nil];
```

Comment: You sure the is a non `nil` value at all possible values of `martix[i][i]`?

Comment: Yeah, everything gets declared as an `int` 0 to 9.

Comment: I think you misunderstand Squeegy's question (and Don's and paull's): split the line `[[resultLabels objectAtIndex:i] setStringValue:resultString];` up into more lines and check for nil values for each object:  `NSArray* labels = resultLabels; id object = [labels objectAtIndex:i]; NSTextField* textField = (NSTextField*)object; [textField setStringValue:resultString];`

Comment: Weird. It errors on `id object = [labels objectAtIndex:i];` even after I `retain` every object in `resultsLabels`.

Comment: Using gdb, what is the result of `po labels`?  What is the value of `i` at that point?

Comment: Also, are these objects local to your method, or properties on the object?  If properties, are they delcared using `retain`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that much about using gdb. I typed `po labels` into the prompt and got `No symbol "labels" in current context.` And they're properties. I tried running `retain` on all of them but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: It sounds to me like resultsLabels itself got released somehow. Did you ever autorelease it or something somewhere along the line?

Comment: When you declare your properties, do they look like this, with the retain: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTextField *result11;`?  To use gdb to inspect an object, set a breakpoint and type `po` (which is "print object") and the name of the object to see what it is at that point.

Comment: They weren't actually properties, just instance variables (confused the terms, sorry!). Making them into properties didn't help either. I ran gdb with breakpoints on different lines and got this: `Cannot access memory at address 0x4`.

Comment: That sounds like you are declaring something incorrectly or dereferencing a pointer incorrectly.  Do you declare resultLabels as `NSArray *resultLabels;` and your text fields as `NSTextField *result11;`?  What are you doing when you get the `Cannot access memory at address 0x4` result?

Comment: It could be that on the i=4 iteration of the loop, you are going past the end of one of the dimensions of `matrix`.  Can you show how `matrix` is declared and initialized?

Comment: I got `Cannot access memory at address 0x4` after placing a breakpoint at `NSArray* labels = resultLabels;` and `id object = [labels objectAtIndex:i];`. `matrix` is declared as a `double [4][4]` in the `@interface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are referencing an object that has been released.  Is your NSArray or objectAtIndex: nil at that point?  Can you show the lines where you instantiate these objects?

Comment: paull - true; I meant memory address 0x0, not nil.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Picky detail: nil and address 0x0 are the same, neither will cause a bad access error; messages to nil return nil.

Comment: I know that you can message nil, but I'm not sure why I never associated 0x0 with nil. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up going with a Objective-C based approach, but I'm accepting this answer since he was so helpful in the comments. Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error on that line, then either `resultsLabels` is released, or the object at `i` is.

Comment: The object at i in your array is a a string, not one of your matrix of ints.

Comment: Oh sorry; you're right. Working on two projects at once gets a little confusing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the source of your crasher, but the `%g` format code is for doubles not ints; you want %d.

The items in the array would be automatically retained by the array (objects in Foundation collections are always retained by the collection), so you shouldn't need to send them extra `-retain` messages. So it would seem as though `resultLabels` may be getting released somewhere before the crash occurs.

Comment: Actually, I simplified. It's really a `double` that gets changed later on. The `retainCount` in the `init` method is 1, but it crashes when it gets called in a different method. I thought nothing happens if a message is sent to a `nil` object, which is why this is so puzzling.

Comment: Nothing does happen, and your comment elsewhere in this question shows that your NSArray points to 0x4.  So I would guess that you have possibly assigned one of your ints to the array pointer somehow.